# Retrieve subjects with no value for a property?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'm getting a list of names from the [German DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql) belonging to "Haus Liechtenstein" with this query:

```sql
select ?name where {
  ?name dcterms:subject category-de:Haus_Liechtenstein
}
```

I want only the people from this list who are still living. There is a property **dbo:deathDate** used for deceased people. How can I restrict my results to individuals *without* a value for **dbo:deathDate**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How can I filter this list for people WITHOUT the Property "dbo:deathDate"?*

You use **filter** to keep only those where there does **not exist** a triple of the form **?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?something**:

```sql
select ?name where {
  ?name dcterms:subject category-de:Haus_Liechtenstein
  filter not exists { 
    ?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?deathDate
  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%20%3Fname%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fname%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fde.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FKategorie%3AHaus_Liechtenstein%3E.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fname%20dbpedia-owl%3AdeathDate%20%3FdeathDate%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Joshua, that helped me a lot! We can also use:

```
SELECT ?name
   WHERE {
     ?name dcterms:subject category-de:Haus_Liechtenstein.
     MINUS {?name dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?d}
         }
```